# Unable to delete plugin

Tags: plugins, uninstall

In updating a plugin for Craft 3, at one point I also renamed it, and at various times did things in the wrong order. At this point, Craft shows the old, unwanted plugin, but

- it is not in `composer.json`
- it is not in the `craft_plugins` table
- none of its tables are in the database
- its files have been deleted from craft/vendor/ns/plugin

On the CP Plugins page, if I click *Remove*, composer updates and says it is successfully removed, but it still shows up under plugins.

How does Craft still know of its existence? Do I need to put it back into composer to do a `composer remove`?

Comment: If it's not in `composer.json`, it may still be in `composer.lock`. Try running `composer update` to make them match.

Comment: Thank you Lindsey. I did that, then tried to remove again. Same results. It acts like it's removing, but the plugin still shows up.

Comment: Weird... if you nuke your `vendor` and `composer.lock` and run `composer update` from the command line does that help?

Comment: Have you tried clearing / removing the cache?

Comment: Which cache? I've certainly done Clear Caches from the CP, but I don't think that's what you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I'm not in favor of the nuclear option in international politics, it works very fine and simply this case. Brad's suggestion of deleting the `craft/vendor` folder and `composer.lock` and then running
`composer update`
solved the problem immediately. Now I appreciate composer.